# adaptive cursor sharing (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle-cursor

If I set CURSOR_SHARING parameter to FORCE, and I issue a statement like

```
select * from customers where region = 'NORTH'
```

, then Adaptive cursor sharing happens only if there is a histogram in the REGION column, or it happens irrespective of whether there is a histogram on that column?

Does exist a relationship between cursor_sharing FORCE, Adaptive cursor sharing and histograms, in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: This material can be useful to you: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/explain_adaptive_cursor_sharing_behavior_with_cursor_sharing_similar_and_force

Comment: "By setting cursor_sharing to force and letting adaptive cursor sharing kick in, the optimizer can choose optimal plans for different values, but if the same plan is appropriate for several values, they will share a single child cursor."

Ok, but I don't understand exactly if Adaptive cursor sharing happend only if there is a histogram, or it happens irrespective of this?

Comment: Tom Kyte discussion - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:599762300346943686 - "Hi Tom,

Can you clarify that for ACS to create new plans for different bind variable values, there must be 
a histogram for the column that the bind variable relates to?

Thanks



Followup   May 6, 2013 - 6pm UTC:

no, there could be any sort of statistic that would cause us to create different plans for different literal values. 

such as local partition statistics for example... 

it would be safe to say that histograms are the prevalent cause, but they are not the sole cause."

Comment: What I understand from this, is that in my case, ACS happens irrespective of whether or not there is a histogram on REGION column. Correct?

Comment: Let's separate two different questions. In accordance to Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm

"Adaptive cursor sharing is enabled for the database by default and cannot be disabled."
So ACS are enabled by default, yes.
But as you can see there further the optimizer should have something that allows
it to make a decision what the current plan for particular bind variable is ineffective.
So you need histograms or partition statistics or something what allows optimizer to make a decision.